# Efficiency vs effectiveness in an example - isn't it wrong?

Tags: process, definition, theory

I have just read an example: *Consider there are sales representatives whose weekly goal is to make 70 calls. That reflects the effectiveness. Then the amount of these calls leading to successful deals is the efficiency.*

Well, isn't effectiveness about doing the right thing and producing the result? I would say that a sales rep. is only effective if he actually sells (that is the desired outcome). So if he makes 70 calls a week, then I would say he is efficient enough (he could maybe do more but also less, and that reflects resources - time) but if he sold nothing, then he is not effective at all. He is probably not doing the right thing (selling) even though he does it right (fast enough).

Or is my understanding incorrect, did I miss something?

Comment: Odd example. I agree that the ability to close the deal in each call is effectiveness. Making 70 calls hardly seems like anything. He could have made those 70 calls efficiently or not.

Comment: This question might better fit English Stack Exchange. If the goal is to make calls, then meeting the call quota is the effect sought. The number of sales per quota of calls is being used as a proxy metric for process efficiency, but it's really just an indirect measurement of the _effectiveness_ of the sales process. The foundational error is defining "effective" as making *y* calls rather than making *x* sales when **making more sales with fewer calls exemplifies efficiency.** The whole thing is therefore an X/Y problem, a bad analogy, and unrelated (albeit transferrable) to project mgmt.

Comment: If the goal is X. then effectiveness is meeting the goal; efficiency is the resources used to meet the goal.  I agree that the goal here is ill selected, but efficiency and effectiveness are, I believe, correctly defined within the example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Effectiveness** is doing the right things.
>
> **Efficiency** is doing things right.

This is something I heard from Scott Hanselman. The larger quote goes [like this](https://deepstash.com/idea/17943/effectiveness-is-doing-the-right-things-but-efficiency-is-doing):

> Effectiveness is doing the right things, but efficiency is doing things right. That means effectiveness is picking a direction and efficiency is running really fast in that direction.

One is goal oriented, one is process oriented.

This stuck with me because I'm not a native English speaker and I used to use the words interchangeably until I encountered the quote. If you look up the dictionary definitions of the two words, you get the same explanation, although not as catchy :).

So, if you make 70 calls but no sale, then you are efficient (i.e. you have a good process in place), but not very effective (i.e. you missed your goal). So, yes, your understanding is correct.

I would argue that in any process, effectiveness is more important than efficiency, because the whole point is to reach a goal, or a result, or an outcome. Even the most efficient process in the world won't help you if you are running thoward the wrong goal.

So it's easy to mess things up if you confuse your goal with what you are doing to reach that goal. In your example with the sales representatives, the goal is to make succesfull deals, not make 70 calls a week. And you rightly noticed that, and that's why you asked this question.

There are solutions to increase effectiveness and efficiency. Of the top of my head I can think of:

- **making more calls per week**. If they make 100, 200 or 300 calls per week, you get a better chance of making deals. It's like in a lottery: the more tickets you buy, the more chances you have of winning. Making more calls means increasing efficiency, but it might not necessarily mean you will get better results if the representatives aren't convincing. They might even become less effective because their incentive now becomes to make more calls not necessarily make more deals (i.e. that is to say, be careful what you measure because you are going to get it). This gets me to the next bullet point.
- **find a better speech or offer better deal conditions**. You can keep your 70 calls per week for example, but try to be more convincing. This solution works on increasing effectiveness. If you can be more successful in producing the desired result (i.e. deals) then you might even notice you can make less calls. You might now say you have a less efficient process (making less than 70 calls) but with a more effective result.
- **prioritize the calls** (as you mentioned in the comments). Maybe you want to call larger clients first, or clients with whom you have a better relation, or clients you managed to convince before. This way you improve efficiency because you are not wasting time with calls that have a low chance of resulting in a succesfull deal. You might improve effectiveness if past indicators of succesfull deals prove to be a good predictor of future deals, but just as well it's possible to have no impact at all and you would still need to make the rest of the less important calls.

What I'm trying to say is effectiveness and efficiency don't always get affected by the same thing. It depends a lot on the context. There are solutions that work on both dimensions (effectiveness and efficiency), some that work on one dimension which in turn affects the other dimension in a positive or negative way (or even not at all), and solutions that might not do anything at all regardless. And people can always look at the same solution from different perspectives and some to see an improvement in effectiveness and others an improvement in efficiency. Just remember what the goal is.

Comment: Thanks, yet I am still not sure, consider the following: you have 100 tests that you have to run, for each you define its importance. Now, you have time to run only the 30 of them, so you choose those with the highest importance, of course.  Did you improve efficiency or effectiveness?

Comment: You didn't improve anything. For example, for the tests to be effective you need to run all 100 tests. If you only run 30 (doesn't matter it's the most important ones) you basically decrease the effectiveness of the tests. One part of the tests are not as effective as all of the tests. So you need to run all 100 tests to be effective. To do that you need to make the tests run faster in order to improve thir execution efficiency. If the tests are more time efficient then you will manage to fit all 100 tests in the same time it now takes you to run just 30...

Comment: ... so basically, **to increase effectiveness you need to add more tests, to increase efficiency you need to make the tests run faster**.

Comment: I think I did not make it clear - this prioritization is a typical example and most authors say it improve effectiveness, some say efficiency. You have to realize it is about running the most important tests only, compared to running some random 30 tests.

Comment: I stand by what I said. It doesn't matter it's the most important tests. That improves nothing. First of all it decreases effectiveness. Why have 100 tests if you only run the most important 30? Are the rest unimportant? Even useless then? Second, I don't see how running the most important tests instead of all tests is an improvement in efficiency. Your testing process wasn't improved. You just cheated by chopping it off :). Prioritization might work in your original example. See my edited answer for more details on that. But what works with sales might not work with tests. Context matters.

Comment: Ok, I can see you do not understand the context. The point of prioritization is to achieve the best result if your time is limited. So, imagine you have 100 tests for a software system, 30 of which deal with high priority features, and 70 deal with features that are not crucial. Now you are told you have only time to execute 15 of them (for whatever reasons like budget cut, time pressure), and of course any sane manager chooses some of the high priority ones. Most book authors say this improves effectiveness of such activity, some say efficiency.

Comment: Otherwise I agree with you. Even easier way to understand that is to realize that effectiveness is actual/desired output, while efficiency is useful outcome/spent resources. So if you are expected to hit 10 sales and you hit 9, your effectivness is 90%. However, if it took you 1000 calls than your efficiency is 0.009.

Comment: @JohnV: If you only have time to run 30 test out of 100, it would be an increase in effectiveness if you choose the most valuable tests, compared to randomly selecting 30 tests. It would be an increase in efficiency if you can do 35 instead of 30 tests in the same time.

Comment: @JohnV: I understand what you are saying. I'm just disagreeing with the statement that *Most book authors say this improves effectiveness of such activity, some say efficiency*. It makes sense to run the most important tests first if you have time constraints or what not, but that doesn't improve anything. It just tries to make the best out of an unfortunate situation.

Comment: @Bogdan No, that is not true. You can actually calculate it and see for yourself: suppose you have 10 critical defects in the system. If you run 30 high priority test cases, you will discover all of them. If you run random 30 tests, you discover maybe some of them. The effectiveness is therefore higher when targeterd, high priority tests are used. I can send you a dozen of links to books where this is explained, as well articles ;) But I believe it was my bad explanation and poor English..

Comment: Here is a full research article dealing with the exact problem: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/301428060_Measuring_the_Effectiveness_of_Test_Case_Prioritization_Techniques_Based_on_Weight_Factors/fulltext/573b34dd08ae9ace840ea1a4/Measuring-the-Effectiveness-of-Test-Case-Prioritization-Techniques-Based-on-Weight-Factors.pdf  Or another one, again improving effectiveness through prioritization: https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/An-effectiveness-test-case-prioritization-technique-Dobuneh-Jawawi/4f820bd94d0b04aef6d8cb042dc1c360af5d70db

Comment: @JohnV: I've read the articles and I finally understand. **It's all about the constraint**. You don't have time to run all 100 tests so you have to chose the ones that bring the most value in finding bugs. Prioritization can indeed improve things. With limited time available, you are indeed more efficient if you run something that has a bigger chance of finding defects. And if you run the important tests first you can also improve effectiveness because carefully selected tests can find defects early on as opposed to tests at random. **But the improvement is just over the constrained time**

Comment: You initially said you have 100 tests and you can only run 30. So you chose the most important ones to run. *Did you improve efficiency or effectiveness?* Overall you didn't improve anything; adding more test or making them run faster improves things overall (as I stated above). But if you consider the time constraint, then prioritization can indeed improve both efficiency and effectiveness in finding defects (as I stated in my previous comment just above this one). **If you are time constrained, prioritization improves things. If you are not time constrained, then it improves nothing**.

Comment: @Bogdan Glad our understanding is the same ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Effectiveness

A measure of the success of a specific action, or series of actions, in achieving a desired state / goal / mission. In order to determine / measure effectiveness, there must be a clear distinction between the current state and the desired state, and there must be a gap / mismatch between the two that needs to be addressed.

Determining the desired state can be complex and may require input from stakeholders, industry knowledge, etc. But in the example you give, the desired state / goal is well defined: make 70 calls/week. The question to measure effectiveness is, was that done or not? If yes, then the person was effective. To me the goal in this example isn't the best since, as you observed, it's possible to achieve the goal and not get any sales done.

Another example is when someone is unemployed. Their desired state is to be employed, and the effectiveness of their job search action(s) would be determined by whether or not they are able to successfully secure a job. This goal also isn't the best too because it's possible to invest 50 years and only get a job then. While it'd be effective in light of the goal / desired state, it's not efficient.

After discussing with [Tom Graves](https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:7006180196940685312?commentUrn=urn%3Ali%3Acomment%3A%28activity%3A7006180196940685312%2C7006733974219755521%29), felt the need to also clarify that while achieving a goal may lead to an action being considered effective (when effectiveness isn't well defined), it is important to consider the values and ethics behind the actions taken to achieve that goal.

Simply putting it, a company may set a goal to make 250,000€ in their first year. While stealing may be an "effective" method to achieve that goal, it goes against the values of honesty and integrity and would not be considered an ethical or effective way to reach the goal.

A company's values are often closely aligned with its vision of and for the world. Since the values will guide the company's actions, it is important to consider them carefully and consistently, rather than simply following what others are doing.

## Efficiency

Measuring the resources used to achieve a desired state. From the previous examples

- In the call center we'd consider things like the amount calls that lead to successful deals, or the time it took to get there.
- In the job search we'd consider things like the number of job applications submitted, or the time it took to reach the desired state.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Parsing what other people mean or intended to say is a fool's game when you're asking about actual definitions. Effectiveness and efficiency are correlated, especially within project management, but aren't synonyms. The former is about achieving goals or delivering something fit for purpose, while the latter is about the level of effort and resource usage required (or wasted) to achieve a given result.

You can be effective in delivering a product by working harder than necessary, or efficiently work on a bunch of tasks that add no value to the delivered product. Nevertheless, a project is more likely to achieve its objectives effectively if work on the project is performed efficiently.

### Brief Analysis

Your quote is about sales, not project management. Aside from potentially being off-topic, it's misleading because the goal of sales is to sell things. That means effectiveness is based on whether or not you meet your sales quota, while efficiency is about how much time and effort are being expended as a ratio of calls to sales.

Effort expended in achieving a goal can be a useful metric, but it doesn't really tell you anything about how or whether the process can be improved. Calling people with cats to sell dog food under the theory that pet owners of a different type might just happen to also own dogs and therefore be interested in your company's dog food is likely to be both inefficient and ineffective compared to calling known dog owners. Relying solely on measuring call volume to sales is probably measuring the wrong thing and solving the wrong problem. Sales is not a project, and bad metrics aren't improved by bad analogies.

All your original post does is raise questions about the process, such as whether the sales people are calling the right prospects who have been appropriately prequalified. It certainly points to process problems that impact both effectiveness and efficiency, but trying to *define* those terms within the scope of project management based on an incomplete apples-to-oranges analogy is largely futile. Don't do that.

### Consult Merriam-Webster

It's often useful to read the actual definitions of words, as well as any etymologies or connotations ascribed to a term. Note the following from [the Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/effectiveness) (bold emphasis mine).

> [The words] cover some overlapping territory.
>
> *Efficient* most often describes what is capable of producing desired results without wasting materials, time, or energy. While the word can be applied to both people and things, it is far more commonly applied to things, such as machines, systems, processes, and organizations. The focus of the word is on **how little is wasted or lost while the desired results are produced**.
>
> *Effective* typically describes things—such as policies, treatments, arguments, and techniques—that do what they are intended to do. People can also be described as effective when **they accomplish what they set out to accomplish**, but the word is far more often applied to things.

So, a project can be effective without being efficient, or efficiently ineffective. Of course, ineffective and inefficient projects often fail, so I will simply refer you to the following truisms:

1. An analogy or metaphor is at best a leaky abstraction.
2. Correlation is not causation.
3. Related things aren't necessarily synonyms.
4. Effort does not inherently produce useful results.
5. Reducing wasted effort doesn't intrinsically create useful results.

From a project management perspective, you are looking to optimize budget, schedule, and scope, which often unintuitively involves [maximizing the amount of work *not* done.](http://agilemanifesto.org/principles.html)

In addition, Bob Lewis frequently quotes Demming to reinforce that you often have to [sub-optimize the parts to optimize the whole](https://www.cio.com/article/406970/what-cios-get-wrong-about-optimization.html). This is basically a business process view of systems thinking, where the goal is to prioritize optimizing the system as a whole rather than focusing on optimization at the team or individual levels.

With that in mind, efficiency for its own sake is less important than effectiveness. As a rule of thumb, focusing on efficiency before you've achieved a basic level of effectiveness is precisely what Donald Knuth meant when he said "Premature optimization is the root of all evil.” Whether it's sales or engineering:

1. Make it work (any way you can).
2. Make it right (ensure correctness, sustainability, and fitness for purpose).
3. Make it fast(er)—assuming you need to address speed at all.

Doing those things in any other order is asking for trouble. Focus on that, and definitional concerns of a purely academic nature will take care of themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can measure both effectiveness and efficiency on the task, the output, and the outcome. In your example, effectiveness of the quantity of calls I assume in a period of time is a valid metric to measure. Efficiency tied to the task might be measured by the cost of each call, e.g., miles driven to the customer, the duration of each call, maybe scheduling the calls in such a manner to minimize drive time and fuel, etc.

Of course, the output would also need to be measured, in terms of closed sales, suspects that are qualifed into prospects, requests of quotes, etc. Then you would also identify efficiency metrics tied to those metrics. Then the outcome--profit, revenue, market share--can be measured compared to the efficiency costs of running the sales shop, etc.

I also think that efficiency is limited to the degree of effectiveness in the same way reliability is to validity and precision is to accuracy. You are only efficient when you are effective. If you are not effective, then you cannot be efficient.

Most think the outcome metric is the only valid thing to measure. That is incorrect. The lower level metrics and those metrics that lead to the outcome must also me measured because they indicate the likelihood of achieving the outcome.